# Is there a built in ability to create a REST WCF Web Service?

Tags: .net, web-services, rest

I have created a WCF web service that is very simple, for testing purposes it adds two numbers together and returns the result.

This all works fine from a console app with a reference to the service hosting on my domain.

I created the service by going to

```
New Project -> WCF Web Service Application
```

As I understand, by default this is a SOAP web service, correct??

I am wondering are REST Web Services a built in type of Web Service for WCF, or does it involve work arounds?

I want to be able to call the Web Service by hitting a URL and getting the result back, as I understand this requires the service to be a REST service rather than SOAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default the basicHttpBinding will be used which is soap based. You will want to look at the webHttpBinding to make your service restful. You can find a short guide at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx.

Comment: Thanks I will read this properly today, just had a quick scan now and it looks like what I am after.